# PHP: Clean code so it only uses 1 file

Tags: php, file, sorting

I have a php function I've written that sorts player's fastest race times. However, it's very dirty, me being a beginning php programmer. I want to know how I could write this much simpler so that only 1 file read is being done:

```
function write_scores($name, $time)
{
    $racetimes = "/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/logs/racetimes.txt"; //temporary file
    $test = "/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/logs/test.txt"; //sorted file
    $fh = fopen($racetimes, 'a');
    $lines = file($racetimes);
        fwrite($fh, "$time, $name\n");
    natsort($lines);
    $lines = array_slice ( $lines , 0, 5); //only store 100 scores to speed performance although $racetimes is the one that needs trimming...
    file_put_contents($test, implode("", $lines));
}
```

I've tried removing the racetimes reference, but then nothing gets written. I can't wrap my brain around it. How can this be rewritten so that it only uses 1 file call?

Comment: again, stop using flat files, this is what a data base was written for.

Comment: When using files with [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/fopen), don't forget to call [`fclose()`](http://www.php.net/fclose).

Comment: Files will be closed when the script ends, so it's not strictly necessary to close them.   Still a good idea to call `fclose()`, though, especially on a busy site or if the file will be read or written again during the same request.

Comment: @cHao, if author asks for *clean code*, then file should be closed ASAP. "Clean" does not mean "less lines", it rather means "easy-to-read" (have you ever had thoughts like "*Is this file used anywhere else, if it is left opened here?*"), "leak-less", "bug-less" etc :)

Comment: @binaryLV: "Clean", to me, means "no unnecessary complexity".  Writing a data file at all adds complexity i'd rather avoid anyway -- the case of multiple writers is always in the back of my mind.  In most cases (uploaders aside), a DB would be a more suitable choice.  But even when you have to mess with a file, there are ways to do it without using `fopen` at all.  That would be the *clean* way, in most cases, as then there's nothing to forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a bit weird, writing the file you're reading.  You'd do better to just add the time to the in-memory array, then you could write it out with the other sorted scores.

I took the liberty of removing `$test` from the function.  I'm assuming the goal is to maintain one sorted list of scores.  If you really want two, re-add all the references to `$test`.

```
function write_scores($name, $time)
{
    $racetimes = "/home/duke/aa/servers/demo/var/logs/racetimes.txt";
    $lines = file($racetimes);
    $lines[] = "$time, $name\n";
    natsort($lines);
    if (count($lines) > 100) array_splice($lines, 100);
    file_put_contents($racetimes, $lines);
}
```